# How to forward port to router using python

Tags: python, p2p, portforwarding

I am building python p2p application like p2p instant messenger. I am communicating with other peers using TCP/IP connection. I do not want client to do port forwarding. 
When application starts it should check whether port is forwarded to router if not it should forward it to router.
Is it possible to programaticaly forward the port to router. Or how can I use port 80 for p2p communication as its used by browsers.